# Cannot send ObjectMessage to IBM MQ

Tags: java, ibm-mq, mq

How can I send object message to IBM MQ?
Fragment of my Java code:

```
QueueConnectionFactory cf;
QueueConnection conn;
MQQueueSession sess;
QueueSender sender;
Queue putQueue = null;
Message RQMessage
//...
cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
((MQQueueConnectionFactory)cf).setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
((MQQueueConnectionFactory)cf).setHostName(host_ip);
((MQQueueConnectionFactory)cf).setPort(1414);
((MQQueueConnectionFactory)cf).setQueueManager(MQMgrName);
((MQQueueConnectionFactory)cf).setChannel(MQChannel);
((MQQueueConnectionFactory)cf).setCCSID(1251);
conn = cf.createQueueConnection(" ", " ");
sess = (MQQeueSession) conn.create
putQueue = ((MQQueueSession)sess).createQueue("queue://"+MQMgrName+"/"+putQueueName);
sender = (MQQueueSender) sess.createSender(putQueue);
MyClass rq_obj = new MyClass();
//MyClass is serializable
rq_obj.setid("1111");
System.out.println(rq_obj.toString());
//got string with my object
RQMessage = sess.createObjectMessage(rq_obj);
RQMessage.setStringProperty("prop_name", "prop_value");
Sender.send(RQMessage);
sess.commit();
```

As a result of this code I get a message with `property prop_name = prop_value`, but message's body is null. I don't know why, but maybe I should change properties of my connection factory (`((MQQueueConnectionFactory)cf).setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);)` but even if it is so, I don't know what properties I need.

Comment: Tried to change message type from Message to ObjectMessage, but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to send my data as either XML or JSON rather than as an Object.  Also years ago, the JVMs (sender & receiver) had to be at the same version level otherwise the Object could not be understood/translated.

From the [IBM MQ Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032110_.htm#q032110___exom), it says you should be doing it this way:

```
ObjectMessage objMessage = session.createObjectMessage();
objMessage.setObject(myObj);
publisher.send(objMessage);
```